# Android Need to retrieve String from async to create new marker on maps

Tags: android, maps

I have an activity class which displays a map with current user position. I use an async task to retrieve Json data from server and parse it to get coordinates.

Badly, I didn't manage to get these coordinates (I tried to pass them via a ArrayList).
This is my class, how can I get my values to use them in updatePlaces() ?

My activity :

public class MapActivity  extends Activity {

```
private int userIcon, jewelleryIcon;
private GoogleMap theMap;
private LocationManager locMan;
private Marker userMarker;
private Marker bijouterie;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
ArrayList<Double> jowelleriesLatitudeList;
ArrayList<Double> jowelleriesLongitudeList;

// URL to get JSON
private static String url = "url.json?params";
private static String url2 = "url.json?params";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Portrait only
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    // Check status of Google Play Services
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // Check Google Play Service Available
    try {
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
    }

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    // Google Maps
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);




    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetJson().execute();

    updatePlaces();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        JSONArray array = null;
        try {
            array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
             System.out.println("id --->" + id);
             String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
             System.out.println("url --->" + url);
        //   shopurl.add(url);
             String created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
             System.out.println("created_at --->" + created_at);
             String updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
             System.out.println("updated_at --->" + updated_at);
             String name = jsonObject.getString("name");    
             System.out.println("name --->" + name);
            // shopname.add(name);
             JSONArray photos_urls = jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos_urls");
             System.out.println("photos_urls --->" + photos_urls);
             String address_string = jsonObject.getString("address_string");
             System.out.println("address_string --->" + address_string);
        //   shopaddress.add(address_string);
             JSONObject booklet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("booklet");
             String id_booklet = booklet.getString("id");
             System.out.println("id_booklet --->" + id_booklet);
             String url_booklet = booklet.getString("url");
             System.out.println("url_booklet --->" + url_booklet);
             String created_at_booklet = booklet.getString("created_at");
             System.out.println("created_at_booklet --->" + created_at_booklet);
             String updated_at_booklet = booklet.getString("updated_at");
             System.out.println("updated_at_booklet --->" + updated_at_booklet);
             String document_url = booklet.getString("document_url");
             System.out.println("document_url --->" + document_url);
             String presented = booklet.getString("presented");
             System.out.println("presented --->" + presented);


            }
                }
             catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


             // 2e JSON

          // Creating service handler class instance
             ServiceHandler sh2 = new ServiceHandler();

             // Making a request to url and getting response
             String jsonStr2 = sh2.makeServiceCall(url2, ServiceHandler.GET);

             Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr2);

             JSONArray array2 = null;
            try {
                array2 = new JSONArray(jsonStr2);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (int j = 0; j <array2.length(); j++){

                JSONObject jsonObject2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
                 JSONArray coordinates = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                latitude = coordinates.getString(0);
                Log.d("latitude: ", "> " + latitude);
                longitude = coordinates.getString(1);
                Log.d("longitude: ", "> " + longitude);

                double latitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double longitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                jowelleriesLatitudeList.add(latitudeFromString);
                jowelleriesLongitudeList.add(longitudeFromString);
            //  shoplongitude.add(longitude);
// shoplatitude.add(latitude);

                 JSONObject shop = jsonObject2.getJSONObject("shop");

                    String logo_thumbnail_url = shop.getString("logo_thumbnail_url");
                    System.out.println("logo_thumbnail_url --->" + logo_thumbnail_url);

                    }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        return null;
}   
}

private void updatePlaces(){

    userIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
    jewelleryIcon = R.drawable.pointeur;

    if(theMap==null){
        //map not instantiated yet
    }
    theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
    if(theMap != null){
        //ok - proceed
    }
    theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //update location
    locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
    double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
    LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    //if(userMarker==null) userMarker.remove();

    userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(lastLatLng)
    .title("Vous êtes ici")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
    .snippet("Votre dernière position enregistrée"));

    theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 7.5f), 4000, null);

        // add a marker - test
        LatLng SHOP = new LatLng(46.581002, 0.3421705); 
        bijouterie = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(SHOP)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(jewelleryIcon)));


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();//go back to the previous Activity
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.backin, R.anim.backout);  
}
```

}

Edit: my log

```
01-05 13:57:51.109: W/dalvikvm(12830): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d34300)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity$GetJson.doInBackground(MapActivity.java:197)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at com.begital.votrebijoutier.MapActivity$GetJson.doInBackground(MapActivity.java:1)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-05 13:57:51.109: E/AndroidRuntime(12830):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Call this

        `updatePlaces();`

in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Where should I place onPostExecute()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the asynchronous task, GetJson(), it will call the onPreExecute() method of the AsyncTask. Then, it will move on to updatePlaces(). At some point later, it will execute your doInBackground() code. However, you don't want to call updatePlaces() until after doInBackground() has been called. The solution is to instead put updatePlaces() in GetJson's onPostExecute().

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Where should I put this method? Bellow PreExecute it tells me it never used locally

protected void onPostExecute() {
            updatePlaces();
        }

Comment: You are forgetting onPostExecute's parameter: `@Override protected void onPostExecute(Void result)`

Comment: I don't see how to get latitude and longitude strings from my for loop. The app crashes when I try to add them to list arrays and retrieve them later.

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: NullPointerException. What is line 197?

Comment: LatitudeList.add(latitude); I try to get latitude in a arraylist (not visible in my original code, but same as double latitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double longitudeFromString = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                jowelleriesLatitudeList.add(latitudeFromString);
                jowelleriesLongitudeList.add(longitudeFromString);

Comment: Did you initialize jowelleriesLatitudeList?

Comment: try {
         ArrayList<String> LatitudeList = null;
        ArrayList<String> LongitudeList = null;
        
         for (int j = 0; j <array2.length(); j++){
          
         JSONObject jsonObject2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
          JSONArray coordinates = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("coordinates");
         latitude = coordinates.getString(0);
        Log.d("latitude: ", "> " + latitude);
        
        LatitudeList.add(latitude);
        
        longitude = coordinates.getString(1);
        Log.d("longitude: ", "> " + longitude);
    
        LongitudeList.add(longitude);
         }

Comment: That's not how you initialize an ArrayList. It should be `ArrayList<String> latitudeList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I didn't resolve all my bugs, but you helped me a lot. I'm new to java so sorry for the noobs questions.